# Objects that aren't parented keep on following each other. It was happening in 2.93 and is happening in 3.0

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, parent

This is a gif that shows what's happening. Also, they are not parented only the gear is parented to something else.

[image: Image shows whats happening]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have proportional editing turned on. Click this button at the top of the 3D viewport to turn it off:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>O</kbd> to toggle it on and off.

Comment: Thank you so much I've been trying to fix this for an hour.